# Some letters overlap using TJ

Tags: pdf

I've a basic example from a PDF i'm editing.

The code

```
 /P <</MCID 0>> BDC q                          
0.000008871 0 595.32 841.92 re                 
W* n                                           
BT                                             
/F1 12 Tf                                      
1 0 0 1 56.64 759.96 Tm                        
/GS7 gs                                        
0 g                                            
/GS8 gs                                        
0 G                                            
[(n)4(a)4(m)4(e)] TJ                           
ET                                             
Q                                              
q                                              
0.000008871 0 595.32 841.92 re                 
W* n                                           
BT                                             
/F1 12 Tf                                      
1 0 0 1 109.7 759.96 Tm                        
0 g                                            
0 G                                            
[( )] TJ                                       
ET                                             
Q
```

works prefectly, producing "name" without quotes when I open the pdf.

Sadly, if I change the n with a c, something happens:

[image]

Same thing happen if i write `[(N)4(a)4(m)4(e)] TJ` (capital N) or with `[\(Name)] TJ`
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `[\(Name)] TJ` - this looks broken.

Comment: `[\(name)] TJ` works perfectly fine tho. I'll attach the sample and the exported pdf tomorrow tho.

Comment: The slash there is an error. That might work on current viewer versions but it may well stop working in the next one.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your font is subset, and so does not have a glyph for c. Your PDF viewer may be substituting a glyph from another standard font, but obeying the given metadata width for the c glyph in the font dictionary for your subset font, which will be 0 for a missing glyph. Hence the overwriting.

Edit: this should have been a comment, not an answer. Sorry.

Comment: Considering the 'c' is visible I also would assume that the font has a definition for that glyph (whether embedded or not is a different question), merely its width entry appears to be 0.